# Should we ever use java thread's yield() method in age of preemptive scheduling?

Tags: java, multithreading

Is there any advantage of using yield method nowadays, isn't the underlying CPU / OS handles thread execution by giving every thread CPU time?

Nowadays most of CPU use preemptive scheduling.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#yield()):

> It is rarely appropriate to use this method. It may be useful for debugging or testing purposes, where it may help to reproduce bugs due to race conditions. It may also be useful when designing concurrency control constructs such as the ones in the java.util.concurrent.locks package.